# Apache 2.4 set ProxyTimeout only for ONE URL

Tags: apache-2.4, timeout, proxypass, ajp

I have an issue with Apache proxies.

I was asked to let the connection between Apache and the web client opened, because we are working on SSE.
The problem is that by default the timeout is 60secs. I would like to increase this value significantly, and I found the `ProxyTimeout` directive which is great BUT it increases the timeout for ALL proxies.
On my conf I have multiple ajp proxies, and I would have liked to apply the `ProxyTimeout` only to /test:

```
ProxyPass /test ajp://some_ip:8009/some_URL
ProxyPassReverse /test ajp://some_ip:8009/some_url

ProxyPass /test2 ajp://some_ip2:8009/some_url2
ProxyPassReverse /test2 ajp://some_ip2:8009/some_url2
```

Is there a way to do so?

So far I tested with:
`ConnectionTimeout`
 and 
`ProxyPass /test ajp://some_ip:8009/some_URL timeout=120` to no avail.

I even tried to specify a timeout with a Proxy block:

```
<Proxy "ajp://some_ip:8009/some_url">
Proxyset timeout=10
</Proxy>
```

but again it failed.

I am not familiar with levels of timeout in Apache (I know there are some), and my knowledge of Apache is rather limited.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible because directives inside `<Proxy>` are only read at server-start time rather than after each request.

Hope may come from https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62422

After introducing a "Proxy" context, it should become possible to generically modify proxy settings (`ProxySet`) according to request being served (eg: its URL among other).

Answer (score -1):

Is your mod proxy on?

I see the syntax as

```
<Proxy "http://backend.example.com">
  ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
</Proxy>
```

Source: Apache Documentation

Comment: Yes, mod_proxy is on, with or without timeout value I can see that they are working well. In fact I seek to increase the timeout between Apache and the client, not the timeout between Apache and Tomcat.

Comment: Can you check if you have an entry In your httpd.conf (in server config or vhost config)
    TimeOut 600 (in seconds) . Also please read TimeOut Directive here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I don't have any TimeOut directive anywhere in my config files. 
I already read the doc for this directive but it's rather succinct and does not help me that much...